# Reemplazar valores en multiples columnas basados en condiciones de la propias columnas

Tags: r, replace

Tengo un dataframe de 290 varaibles y debo reemplazar los valores en 146 variables. Estas 146 variables son NA o algún valor númerico entre 3 y 350; lo que neceisto es uniformizar el valor que asumen en cada una de las 146 variables.Si en la variable hay una valor distinto de NA que asuma el valor 1. ¿cómo hago para no repetir la operación 146 veces? O sea necesito hacer un replace en cada variable basado en la condicion de que si el valor de la variable es distinto a NA le ponga 1. La condición es la misma en todos los casos pero utlizando la variable que quiero modificar.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más simple en este caso es partiendo de una matriz de sustitución. Por ejemplo, con esto:

```
set.seed(1)
datos <- data.frame(c1 = sample(c(2:3, NA), 5, replace = TRUE),
                    c2 = sample(c(3:4, NA), 5, replace = TRUE),
                    c3 = sample(c(4:5, NA), 5, replace = TRUE))

datos

  c1 c2 c3
1  2 NA NA
2 NA NA  4
3  2  4  4
4  3  4  4
5  2 NA  5
```

Armamos la matriz de sustitución, dónde los valores `TRUE` indican el valor a modificar, y luego a estos le asignamos el valor 1:

```
modificaciones <- !is.na(datos)
datos[modificaciones] <- 1

datos
  c1 c2 c3
1  1 NA NA
2 NA NA  1
3  1  1  1
4  1  1  1
5  1 NA  1
```

Si tienes una parte del `data.frame` que no quieres modificar, simplemente dividelo en dos, modificas uno y lo vuelves a unir:

```
df1 <- datos[, "c1", drop=FALSE]
df2 <- datos[, c("c2","c3")]

modificaciones <- !is.na(df2)
df2[modificaciones] <- 1

cbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. No me doy cuenta como hago para afectar solo a las variables que necesito. Si genero una matriz con las variables a modificar y luego hago un merge con el resto de la base necesito el id, y no aplicar la sustitución por 1 para ese Id.

Comment: Separas en dos data.frames, uno es el que vas a modificar, luego vuelves a unirlos mediante `rbind(df1, df2)`

Comment: Creo que no me sirve porque yo necesito unir columnas de los dos data frames; y no de cualquier forma si no que se correspondan por un id.

Comment: No, si divides un df en 2, cada fila de uno coincide con la del otro, a menos que la modificación de variables de la que hablas afecte solo a determinadas filas, cosa que no se deduce de tu pregunta. Si este sería el caso, usa la solución que te dí, y antes agrega un  ID sintetico, por ejemplo un numero de fila, luego lo usas para unir los df con el merge.

Comment: Divido en 2 el dataframe, en uno me quedo con las variables que no tengo que modificar (df1) y en otro las que modifico (df2). Si hago esto y luego ejecuto la solución y la aplico en df2 me corre bien. Pero luego para unir no puedo usar rbind, porque ambos dataframe tienen todas las variables diferentes; ¿podría usar bind_rows o usar cbind? pero preferiria usar un marge para unir por un id. Pero no se como hacer la solución sin que me afecte el id Si en la matriz de modificacion no considero el id me dice
! Subscript `modificaciones` is a matrix, it must have the same dimensions as the input.

Comment: Mala mía, no es `rbind` es `cbind`, revisa mi última edición